# Updating Data-Tier Application version via SqlPackage.exe

Tags: sql, command-line, data-tier-applications, dacpac

I am currently automating the deployment of my applications database via command line **using SqlPackage.exe**, but unable to find a way to update the version of my Data-Tier Application

(Development, of course...)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

I am using the /Action:Publish to push my newly built *.dacpac, but version always remains at v1.0.0.0, if this is not possible? How about how to change an ExtendedProperty?

I just want to have a reference to what version is installed by looking at the database.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Including

```
/p:RegisterDataTierApplication=true
```

as part of the command line is what worked for me to have **SqlPackage.exe** update the version stored in data-tier metadata with the version of the DACPAC being published.

In my testing, I've found that setting **RegisterDataTierApplication** to **true** is performing an upgrade if the target database is already registered. Essentially, this property tells **SqlPackage.exe** that the DACPAC should be published as a data-tier package, as opposed to just publishing any changed objects (and therefore causing drift).

So, the full command that I use is

```
SqlPackage.exe /a:publish /tcs:<target connection string> /sf:<DACPAC file path> /p:RegisterDataTierApplication=true /p:BlockWhenDriftDetected=false
```

(I found that I had to include `/p:BlockWhenDriftDetected=false` because **SqlPackage.exe** was returning an error that it detected drift, even though /a:deployreport did not report any drift.)

Answer (score 0):

On your database project go to project settings, there is a section Output types, click on the properties button below "Data-tier Application (.dacpac) file):

In this dialog you can set the version number that then gets deployed, you can then query this information from:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [instance_id]
      ,[instance_name]
      ,[type_name]
      ,[type_version]
      ,[description]
      ,[type_stream]
      ,[date_created]
      ,[created_by]
      ,[database_name]
  FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysdac_instances]
```

Comment: this is how you change it in the project. he asked about changing it in the sqlpackage cmd.